# Need help to figure out why my bootstrap 5.0 carousel isn't working

Tags: carousel, bootstrap-5

Can't seem to figure out why my carousel won't switch around when I click the arrows.

Thank you for all the help !

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
      <img class="test-image" src="images/dog-img.jpg" alt="dog-profile">
      <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
    </div>
 
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
      <img class="test-image" src="images/lady-img.jpg" alt="lady-profile">
      <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
    </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...

1. You also need to add Bootstrap JS, not only CSS.
2. Change `href="#testimonial-carousel"` to `data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel"`.
3. Change `data-slide="prev"` (Bootstrap 4) to `data-bs-slide="prev"` (Bootstrap 5) and `data-slide="next"` (Bootstrap 4) to `data-bs-slide="next"` (Bootstrap 5).

See the snippet below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="main.js"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="testimonial-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <h2>I no longer have to sniff other dogs for love. I've found the hottest Corgi on TinDog. Woof.</h2>
        <img class="test-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/802112/pexels-photo-802112.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="dog-profile">
        <em>Pebbles, New York</em>
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <h2 class="testimonial-text">My dog used to be so lonely, but with TinDog's help, they've found the love of their life. I think.</h2>
        <img class="test-image" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/802112/pexels-photo-802112.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="lady-profile">
        <em>Beverly, Illinois</em>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" data-bs-target="#testimonial-carousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you thank you ! I've been struggling for so long. I think my lesson I'm learning is using outdated resources so it was confusing haha

Is adding javascript just a matter of copying the code into my HTML?

Comment: You're welcome. :) Pay attention if it's Bootstrap 4 or 5. You need to add Bootstrap JS (i.e., `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`) inside the `<head>` like I did above.

Comment: Ah sorry! I didn’t know as it is my first post. Just accepted it! But it won’t let me upvote since my account is new

Comment: No worries, that's why I kindly ask you to do so. It's okay, have a nice day!